# Drawing sharp diagonal lines in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there a way to draw as sharp as possible (pixel-perfect) diagonal lines Photoshop?
I want to create an "X" close button but I can't get it to look good in smaller pixel dimensions such as (16x16).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for pixel-perfect precision, use the Pencil tool (size 1 pt). It may also help to turn on the Pixel Grid (`View → Show → Pixel Grid`):

[image: Pencil Tool]